# How can I center the GMSMapMarker view in a coordinate

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps, markers, gmsmapview

[image]

Is there a way to center the orange arrow (a GMSMapMarker) in a coordinate, changing the view frame or something? I'm using Google Maps for iOS. I can rotate the view with an angle, but I want to set the view's center in a custom coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution using the property groundAnchor of GMSMarker:

`_mapMarker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can calculate the pixel/degree by using the [GMSCoordinateBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds), then you can shift the center bases on your icon size and heading.